# Appending spaces with str_pad

Tags: php, string, padding

I'm trying to print the contents of an array to the screen, but nicely indented:

```
function fu($var){
    $lengths = array_map('strlen', array_keys($var));
    $longest = max($lengths);

    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($var as $key => $value){
      echo str_pad($key, $longest - strlen($key)).' =&gt; '.$value."\n";
    }
    echo '</pre>';
}

fu(array(
   'foo'         => 5, 
   'foooooooooo' => 'xxx', 
   'abc'         => 5454545, 
   '1234567890'  => 34, 
   4352354       => 435, 
   'a'           => 'x',
));
```

For some reason I don't get my output correctly indented.

It should add (max key length) - (key length) spaces. Or isn't my formula correct?

Comment: have you tried print_r? or is this not for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_pad` automatically pads to the length specified, you don't need to alter this number based on the length of the string currently being padded.

Therefore, change:

```
str_pad($key, $longest - strlen($key))
```

to

```
str_pad($key, $longest)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use printf's formatting to do this. Use this instead of your echo line:

```
printf("%-" . $longest . "s =&gt; $value\n", $key, $value);
```

Or, if you want right-align:

```
printf("%" . $longest . "s =&gt; $value\n", $key, $value);
```