# Exact length of entry during writing to the file

Tags: php

I'm doing a task for php lessons. I'm doing quite fine but I have problem with exact length of entry. I have delimited text

```
Igor                 ;111111                  ;
Therese              ;444444                  ;
Martha               ;555555                  ;
```

and so on. But when I write text to this file, the output is sth like that

```
Igor                 ;111111                  ;
Therese              ;444444                  ;
Martha               ;555555                  ;
Martin;123456;
Caroline;1234567;
Victor;123456;
```

My function for writing to the file is quite easy

```
function WriteToFile($path, $file, $mode, $toWriteIn)
    {
        $fp = OpenFile($path, $file, $mode);
        fwrite($fp, "\n$toWriteIn;");
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

and using this function in a file looks like that:

```
WriteToFile($_Secret, $_blabla, "a+",$_GET['name'].";".$_GET['number']);
```

I looked for a solution and I can check size of the name and checking if the length is smaller then, let's say, 25 but maybe there is an easier way to do it

Comment: You're looking for the [`str_pad()`](https://php.net/str_pad) function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9280906/2943403 ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/27745969/2943403 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing to .txt file in columns with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833521/writing-to-txt-file-in-columns-with-php)

Comment: @rickdenhaan that’s what i was looking for, thanks so much.